# writing odd number in a list python

Tags: python

This is a part of my homework assignment and im close to the final answer but not quite yet. I need to write a function that writes the odd number between position 1 and 5 in a list.
I make something like that:
-in a file domain I write the condition for odd number:

```
def oddNumber(x):
    """
    this instruction help us to write the odd numbers from the positions specificated
    input: x-number
    output:-True if the number is odd 
           -False otherwise
    """
    if x % 2==1:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

-then the tests:

```
def testOdd_Number():
    testOdd_Number=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
    oddNumber(testOdd_Number,0,6)
    assert (testOdd_Number==[1,3,5])
    oddNumber(testOdd_Number,0,3)
    assert (testOdd_Number==[3])
```

-and in the other file named userinterface I write this:

```
 elif(cmd.startswith("odd from ", "")):
            try:
                cmd=cmd.replace("odd from ", "")
                cmd=cmd.replace("to ", "")
                i=int(cmd[:cmd.find(" ")])
                j=int(cmd[cmd.find(" "):])
                if (i>=len(NumberList) or i>j or j>=len(NumberList) or i<0 or j<0):
                    print("Invalid value(s).")
                else:
                    for m in range(i-1,j):
                        if oddNumber(NumberList[m]):
                            print (NumberList[m])
            except: 
                    print("Error!")
```

-when I run the entire project(I have more requirements but the others one are good), and write odd from [pos] to [pos] it says me

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Adina\My Documents\LiClipse Workspace\P1\userinterface.py", line 94, in <module>
    run()            
  File "C:\Users\Adina\My Documents\LiClipse Workspace\P1\userinterface.py", line 77, in run
    elif(cmd.startswith("odd from ", "")):
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

I've forgotten to say that I have a also a function main() where I print the requirements.Where am I wrong?

Comment: `cmd[:cmd.find(" ")]` will error if `" "` is not found in `cmd`.

Answer (score 3):

Python's string startswith method, described here:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html
states that arguments are

```
some_string.startswith(prefix, beginning, end) #where beginning and end are optional integers
```

and You have provided prefix and empty string ( cmd.startswith("odd from ", "") )

Comment: To be precise, these are not (only) integers, but rather slice indexes, hence the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Some things I noticed:

1) you can shorten your `oddNumber` function to

```
def oddNumber(x):
    return x%2
```

2) in your tests, you rebind the functions name `testOdd_Number` to some list, then pass that around to your `oddNumber` function. is that the same function described above? Then it won't work, as this function expects a single integer to be passed.

Using the same name to refer to two different things is discouraged.
Actually, I have no idea what your testcode does or should do. Are you passing a list and expect `oddNumber` to modify it in place?

3) your custom command parser looks... odd, and fragile. Maybe invest in a real parser?
You should decouple command parsing and actual computation.

As brainovergrow pointed out, there is also your error, since `.startswith` does not accept a string as second argument.

Some general hints:

- You can use `list(range(9))` instead of hardcoding `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]`
- You can use `filter` to filter the odd numbers of a given list:`>>> list(filter(oddNumber, range(9)))` yields `[1, 3, 5, 7]`.
- You can also use `list comprehensions`: `[x for x in range(9) if x%2]` yields the same.
- you might find `any()` and `all()` useful. Take a look at them.
- Your naming scheme is neighter consistent nor pythonic. Read [PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for a style guide.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I have found the mistake.Thanks also for the hints.